# Assets seems to bog down Matrix

Tags: matrix, assets, playa, pixelandtonic, performance

I've got a calendar page with different months (as entries) containing matrix fields.
The rows contain text, playa, a date field and assets.

With 50 rows, the page takes ten seconds to download. Testing I discovered that removing assets out of the template speeds it up to one second load time.

I've got the latest P&T stuff running on 2.5.5 here,

Only removing assets field: 0.4 seconds loadtime / 13 Mb

Only removing wygwam field: 7.2 seconds loadtime / 13 Mb

Only removing playa field: 6 seconds loadtime / 13 Mb

All fields: 7.2 seconds

The super simple code:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="calendar" show_future_entries="yes"}
{matrix_field}

{assets_field}
{assets_field} {!--need it twice, just the url slows it down already--}

{wygwam_field}

{playa_field}
{title}
{/playa_field}

{/matrix_field}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Comment: Hey noregt - do you have any openbasedir restrictions?  We've found that even having it enabled can cause this kind of performance issue; it's the only time we've been able to reproduce it actually....

Comment: open_basedir has no value, I assume that means that it is not restricted? I could of course check it in a separate installation. But that will take some time.